# DiscordPy Set Bot Nickname

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to get this to work for about an hour now, but my dumb brain cannot figure it out. basically i want to get my bot to set it's own nickname when someone says (prefix)name (namechangeto)

`@client.command(aliases=["nick", "name"])`

`async def nickname(ctx, name="Bot"):`

`user = guild.me()`

`await user.edit(nick=name)`

any help appreciated

(also sorry for bad formatting, and i know this code probably makes some people cringe lol im sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the problem in your code is that your variable `guild` is not defined, so you have to use `ctx.guild` to get the good guild. Besides that, [discord.Guild.me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.me) is not a function (callable with `()`) but an attribute, you just have to use `guild.me`.

So you can try to make :

```
user = ctx.guild.me
await user.edit(nick=name)
```

In addition to that, it's not really the problem but an advice, you can use `async def nickname(ctx, *, name="Bot"):` instead of `async def nickname(ctx, name="Bot"):` to allow user to set a nickname with spaces in it.

So your final code for me is that :

```
@client.command(aliases=["nick", "name"])
async def nickname(ctx, *, name="Bot"):
    user = ctx.guild.me
    await user.edit(nick=name)
```

Have a nice day!

Baptiste